# Change listview scrolling sensitivity

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a horizontal ListView with a series of items with a width of 10 to 20 pixels. The normal scrolling behavior is too responsive in this scenario, making it hard to gently scroll to the next element without passing through it. A nice solution to this UX problem would be to reduce the scrolling sensitivity/speed, by decreasing the offset of each swipe. unfortunately I couldn't find anything regarding this scenario. Any help would be really useful.